# Beginner in Java using JUnit to test an ArrayList size

Tags: java, junit

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get all Points in Shape is working and gets the correct number output")
    public void test_Get_All_Points_On_Shape()
    {
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(Arrays.asList(new Point[4]));
        assertEquals(points.size() == 4);
    }
```

the above code gives an error

```
The method assertEquals(short, short) in the type Assertions is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Couple of remarks:
- ArrayList<Point> could be replaced by LIst<Point>
- assertEquals should be assertTrue(points.size() ==4)
- assertEquals can be used, for example assertEquals(points.size(),4)
- assertEquals can be used, for example assertEquals("points are not the same",points.size(),4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you use

```
assertTrue(points.size() == 4);
```

or

```
assertEquals(4, points.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `assertThat()` from `org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat` or from `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat`

then you can use:

```
assertThat(points).hasSize(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(long,%20long)

The `assertEquals` method requires two parameters. Replace your code as
`assertEquals(4,points.size());`

Answer (score 1):

The method assertEquals() takes two parameters:

- expected value and
- actual value

What you passed is a result of equality operator on two integers, which is boolean.

You have to change this line to the following:

```
 assertEquals(4, points.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Assert options appropriately as per your need.
two easy methods that can be used for your case is

```
assertEquals(4, points.size());
assertTrue(points.size() == 4);
```

depending on your requirement, you can use the **assertFalse()** which is also a much used method.